# Jboss autodeployment of exploded war not working

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss

i was able to autodeploy my exploded war file under standalone/deployment folder , and suddenly my auto deployment stopped working

i am using eclipse IDE, where i have my projects and using ***File Sync*** plugin i am moving my testweb.war file to my JBoss AS 7.1 server deployment folder.

i have made below changes in my jboss admin console to achieve autodeploy exploded war.

[image]

i have tried cleaning standalone configuration directory, but same result, autodeployment was not happening when there is a file change in the exploded.war.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since i was deploying exploded war file only, i have unchecked Auto-deploy unzipped and made false, then after autodeployment for exploded war file started working in my jboss.